# How do I unload a library after it is LD_PRELOAD'ed?

Tags: ld, child-process, ld-preload

We **LD_PRELOAD** a library for some feature, if I want to disable the feature and want to unload the library is there a way to do that ? I **don't** want to use **RTLD**, it has to be a LD_PRELOAD only so don't suggest dlsym.

Also another use case is in case of **LD_PRELOAD** any child process created by a process also has the same environment which I don't want. Is there a way this can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just reset the variable setting it to an empty string.

In C you can do:

```
int ret = unsetenv("LD_PRELOAD")
```

Also, you can set it from inside a code with [setenv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html)

Comment: This will unload all the environment how about we if we want to unload any particular path ? Should we do something like getenv then unsetenv and again setenv ?

Comment: Probably, since there is only one environment variable I don't think you can just unload one of them.   If there is a way to do it without not going through all the values in the LD_PRELOAD variable I am not aware of it.